# Changing system shortcuts like Undo without side effects

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, undo-redo

On german keyboards the system shortcut for `Undo` is the same as on an english keyboard: <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd>.

The problem: On a german keyboard layout the <kbd>z</kbd> key is switched with the <kbd>y</kbd> and as such very inconvenient to reach with left hand only. (On english keyboard it would be the same as pressing <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>y</kbd> - not ergonomic)

Using `System Preferences` > `Keyboard` > `Shortcuts` and adding a custom `App Shortcut` does not seem to work as <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>y</kbd> collides with other application shortcuts (e.g. Redo in Sublime).

So what are my options to remap the undo shortcut system-wide so that pressing <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>y</kbd> triggers it, without side effects?

Preferably I would not like to use third party solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending more time on this issue, I think I've found a solution: User defined macOS keyboard layouts. These allow remapping modifier combinations like <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>key</kbd> while leaving <kbd>key</kbd> untouched.

While keyboard layouts xml files can be edited manually, using [Ukulele](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/) makes this process a lot less error prone.

In Ukulele create a keyboard layout from your active layout. Then keeping <kbd>command</kbd> pressed switch the output string for <kbd>y</kbd> and <kbd>z</kbd>:

[image]

Now either use Ukulele to add this keyboard layout to the active layouts or copy it to `~Library/Keyboard Layouts`. After log out / log in the new layout can be selected and becomes active.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt you'll manage this natively - because there is no system-wide undo/redo sequence.
Some apps use still use the older  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Y</kbd>  , many others the newer  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>Z</kbd>  .

You can, of course, change any menu command, but you can't change a command that doesn't have a menu item. You also cannot wildcard a menu name.
Just to take an example from Safari.  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Z</kbd>  is currently 'Undo Typing'

[image]

However, if I close a tab it becomes 'Undo Close Tab'

[image]

Once you Undo, then your Redo becomes similarly context-sensitive

[image]

You would have to try to make one new key command for each potential menu item & also ignore that the Keyboard prefs page is going to keep shouting at you that you have duplicates.

You might be able to get something like [Karabiner Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org) to globally change those specific key combinations around. There are some pre-made 'recipes' to do some fairly complex reassignments, but it's not something I've studied. See https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/#Keychron%20K6